# 4 25% width elements dont fit in a 100% element

Tags: css-float

I have 1 .infobox div with 4 nested .detailbox divs the last (.detailbox) div floats in a new row, under the first element. Why is that? Its supposed to fit in there :-) I already tried margin and padding. No success. Thanks

```
.infobox {
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: 'border-box';
-moz-box-sizing: 'border-box';
box-sizing: 'border-box';
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #dedede;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 40px;
margin:0px
}

.infobox .detailbox {
height: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 25%;
box-sizing: 'border-box';
-moz-box-sizing: 'border-box';
-webkit-box-sizing: 'border-box';
float: left;
padding: 10px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
text-align: center;
margin:0px
}

.infobox .detailbox:last-child {
border-right: none !important
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the quotes from `'border-box'` and it works for me. More about box-sizing here: http://www.peterkroener.de/schoenes-neues-css-box-sizing/

BR
Chris